# SharePoint Online RER, how to access properties of a Microsoft.sharepoint.client.file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, spfile

I have a ItemAdded remote event receiver for a document library in the host web. Event receiver works fine. However I would like to access the properties of the file object. (Would like to see the properties for a office document)

The file object does not have properties exposed but the MSDN post below says the file members have public properties exposed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_members.aspx

Has anyone ever worked out a way to read the Microsoft.sharepoint.client.file properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the above problem to access custom file properties using OpenXML.

In this instance, I had to either create a WordProcessingDocument or SpreadsheetDocument from the ﻿﻿File stream depending on the file type.

once I have the document I able to read the CustomFilePropertiesPart and access the properties as required.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,

ShanVeer.

Answer (score -2):

```
string filename = Convert.ToString(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"]);
```

Comment: add some explanation how your answer can help **OP**

Comment: Explanation will give more highlight on the resolution